# Brush and Zoom D3 Explain

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I'm following this guide: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/34f08d5e11952a80609169b7917d4172

Can you explain to me these two methods line by line? Thanks

```
function brushed() {
  if (d3.event.sourceEvent && d3.event.sourceEvent.type === "zoom") return; // ignore brush-by-zoom
  var s = d3.event.selection || x2.range();
  x.domain(s.map(x2.invert, x2));
  focus.select(".area").attr("d", area);
  focus.select(".axis--x").call(xAxis);
  svg.select(".zoom").call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity
      .scale(width / (s[1] - s[0]))
      .translate(-s[0], 0));
}

function zoomed() {
  if (d3.event.sourceEvent && d3.event.sourceEvent.type === "brush") return; // ignore zoom-by-brush
  var t = d3.event.transform;
  x.domain(t.rescaleX(x2).domain());
  focus.select(".area").attr("d", area);
  focus.select(".axis--x").call(xAxis);
  context.select(".brush").call(brush.move, x.range().map(t.invertX, t));
}
```

Comment: it is all in the docs at d3js.org

Comment: What link? @rioV8

Comment: https://github.com/d3/d3-brush

Comment: Thanks for link @Danny